# tab hover with CSS

Tags: html, css, less

In these three cases, is there a way to write in CSS?

1. In **normal** mode
2. In **hover** mode
3. **Out** of hover

```
.tab:hover:nth-of-type(1) ~ .tab__content:nth-of-type(1) {
opacity: 1;
transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease;
transition: 0.5s opacity ease-in, 0.8s transform ease, 0.8s -webkit-transform ease;
position: relative;
top: 0;
z-index: 100;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
transform: translateY(0px);
text-shadow: 0 0 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlkde.jpg)

[js](https://jsfiddle.net/vjq29utg)

Comment: Sadly what you want can't be handle by CSS. You have to use JS for this

Comment: Hi Maryam. Could you describe in more detail what you need help with.

Comment: Can you make a project? (jsFiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only `:hover` in CSS but in Javascript you have `mouseover` and `mouseout` if that's of any use?

Comment: This article explains more on the JS way: https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave#events-mouseover-mouseout-relatedtarget

Comment: Can you make a project? (jsfiddle)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @daniel-knights I don't know about Java, Does it work?
You run a project on the JSFIDDLE site.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Knights/yc50s6oh/19/

Comment: You'd have to make a few changes to your CSS etc. but it allows for more control. jQuery is probably better if you want less code involved but it's best to learn the JS way first before you move on to that.

Comment: yes... But it's not like this photo ... `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlkde.jpg`

Comment: Oh, do you mean the content stays showing after the mouse leaves the tab?

Comment: I may need a hundred tabs. I can't write all these hundreds of Javascript like this

Comment: You loop through each tab and tab-content and match their datasets? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Knights/yc50s6oh/37/. Though, if you'll need it for hundreds of tabs I'd suggest dynamically inserting datasets and incrementing a number value for each.

Comment: Unless you want to hard code it but that would take a long time and look very messy.